# Polyhedra triangulated on a plane

Tags: surface-deform

Hi I want to create a circular shape with polyhedra triangles.
So I can push or pull the connection spots up and down.

Eventually I want to have the structure of polyhedra into a "flat" circular surface to make it in to a 4mm plate with the structure on both sides of the plate.

This is how far I've got.

UPDATE: To simplify: I don't want the spherical result. I want a "plane" with the surface of the polyhedra shape.

[image: testleft]
This is sort of what I want.
I want a disc with the triangulated mesh in it. So I can push-pull  the point inwards and outwards. The disc itself should be 5mm thick and have the same triangulated points on the bottom as on the top.

[image: testabove]

[image: polyhedrashape]

Comment: I'm a bit confused, do you want to flatten all the vertices you have and then turn it into the example below?

Comment: @NascentSpace No, the spherical shape hase inward and outward pushed vertices.
I want to have a "flat" circulare surface with the same vertices inward and outwards.

Comment: I think you're going to have to specify this more closely. Do you want  a view of the surface's vertices  projected into the flat circle's geometry, or what? Can you illustrate the desired relation between 3D and 2D?

Comment: @RobinBetts I want a disc with the triangulated mesh in it. So I can push-pull the point inwards and outwards. The disc itself should be 5mm thick and have the same triangulated points on the bottom as on the top.

Comment: what are "polyhedra triangles"? "So I can push or pull the connection spots up and down." - you can do it with any subdivided plane. "Eventually I want to have the structure of polyhedra into a "flat" circular surface" - and yet somehow Jag's answer doesn't satisfy you? " I want a disc with the triangulated mesh in it." - OK, create a disc, and CTRL+T triangulate it. Done. "he disc itself should be 5mm thick and have the same triangulated points on the bottom as on the top." - extrude the disc down, and triangulate again to convert side quads to triangles…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with a plugin Looptools.

1. making a circle.
2. Adding a grid fill then adding subdivide.
3. Extrude the whole thing

And eventually just pulling the points up and downwards of the triangles!

Worked like charm, got the info from a friend.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed as stated, the question would benefit from clarifications.

Anyway, here's a tentative to answer from what I understood.

First create an icosphere that looks a bit like what you're aiming for.

[image]

Remove the lower part then flatten the half sphere.

[image]

[image]

Using the dissolve tool (CTRL+X) and the knife tool (K), create the pattern of your liking:

[image]
[image]

Finally , using proportional editing with the spherical option, grab the center part and raise it as far as you need it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's not exactly what I want. This is more flattening the object, which results in a sphere like object. I want a disc with the triangulated mesh in it. So I can push-pull  the point inwards and outwards.

Answer (score 1):

Create a circle mesh. Define the number of verts you want. Go to edit mode, select all verts and press f to fill with a face. Press I and inset just a little bit and click. Press M to merge all those points, choose merge at center. [image]